# Code formatter for Play's .scala.html template files

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0, scala-ide

The [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) is a web framework for Scala and Java.
Its Scala interface uses `.scala.html` template files for automatically generating HTML files.
Is there a tool for automatically formatting these files?

Some more context: In Eclipse, with the Scala and Play plugins, the formatter can automatically format Scala source files and the routes file, but it does nothing on `.scala.html` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA is able to format Scala templates.

There is an open feature request for the ScalaIDE Play plugin for formatting Scala Templates:

https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide-play2/issues/118

Answer (score 2):

There also is a [Sublime Text plugin](https://github.com/guillaumebort/play2-sublimetext2) edited by Guillaume Bort himself.

Answer (score -1):

The Pleasure play Plugin (NetBeans Plugin for play framework) is able to format scala templates too: [scala templates features on pleasure](http://nbpleasureplugin.com/documentation/scala_templates.html)

> Format the code using the NetBeans way: just pressing Alt+Shift+F or
>   right click the file -> and select Format
>
> Note that the number of spaces between columns can be specified at
>   Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Play Framework and specifying the
>   amount of spaces in the Scala Templates indent Spaces text field.

Note: I created this plugin